# How to get my path written with back slashes instead of forward slashes?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, operating-system

I hope someone can help as I am stuck, I can't find the answer to this problem anywhere on google.

I need to replace my forward slash path with a backslash path in order for it to work with windows command prompt. Forward slash paths work for local folders, i.e. C:/Users/Lorcan - but not network folders, i.e. //Networkfolder/Storage

I learned that you can't use the backslash in python as it is a special character, so you must use two backslashes. However, this causes my path to have too many backslashes, and command prompt doesn't work.

```
>>> s = '//Networkfolder/Storage/Myfolder/Myfile'
>>> s2 = s.replace('/','\\')
>>> s2
'\\\\Networkfolder\\Storage\\Myfolder\\Myfile'
```

Comment: you should almost-certainly use pathlib at least as a base for your pathing needs! https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Please read the Python documentation pages about [Built-in Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) with the chapter [Text Sequence Type — str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) and [Common string operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html). I recommend to read also the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) explaining why the usage of `/` instead of ``\`` __usually__ (not always) works because of automatic correction by the Windows I/O functions.

Comment: The Python documentation page [Lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) with chapter [2.4.1. String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings) should be also read to get a complete knowledge about how to handle text strings in Python scripts. How the string value of a variable of type `str` is output and how the string value is in memory on script execution are two different things. You should understand the difference on having full knowledge about type `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the python shell, backslashes are displayed as `\\`, but it's really `\` in the string. Your code is working fine, the real string is correct, it's being displayed like that.

Comment: When I do this, it gives me an error:
```
>>> s2 = s.replace('/',r'\')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    s2 = s.replace('/',r'\')
                            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: But when I use the replaced string in my code (I am using it to run command line options for a program) - it seems to be using this '\\\\Networkfolder\\Storage\\Myfolder\\Myfile' folder as the folder location for the command line options and it doesnt work

Comment: apologies, it is actually working with the code I posted above, as you say it will display \\ but its actually \. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can print out your current working directory instead of writing it out:

```
import os

cwd = str(os.getcwd())
x = cwd.replace("/", "\\")
print(x)
```

This worked for me, hope it does for you as well!